# Removing "prev" link from an article

Tags: joomla1.5

I am new to Joomla. I want to remove only the "< prev" navigation link from one of my articles and keep the "next >" from one of my pages. 
Can someone help me how to do that ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that pagination is a core component of Joomla! You can disable the entire function (both prev and next) from displaying but in order to edit it so that only the next is visible would require modifying that core code of the pagination feature. I wouldn't directly recommend this as it means that with every Joomla! update you will either need to not update the hacked pagination code or rehack it every time.